# Yii::$app->request не работает на сервере

Tags: yii2

Yii 2 не работает корректно на сервере Advenced шаблон.
В контроллере делаю так

```
 $searchModel = new OrdersSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
```

Но если делаю

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);exit;
array(1) { ["/orders/index"]=> string(0) "" }
```

то есть мне не выводятся параметры из GET запроса `(http://site.com/backend/web/orders/index?OrdersSearch[page]=50&OrdersSearch[date_start]=&OrdersSearch[date_end]=)`
На локальном компьютере все работает, а вот на сервере не хочет...

Answer (score 0):

Я вас не до конца понял, но похоже на то, что у вас включен prettyUrl в yii, но не настроен web-сервер под такой формат URL.
Чтобы проверить можно:
в config/main.php найти enablePrettyUrl, установить ему значение false и попробовать снова.
Если это исправит ситуацию, но вы захотите иметь ЧПУ url, то вам придется настроить WEB-сервер. Например для апача записать в web/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```